# How do I increase the stack size for Apache running under Windows 7?

Tags: apache, stack-overflow, windows-7-x64

I think I am getting stack overflows running a cakePHP application on an Apache server under Windows 7.

Comment: Needs more info. What crashes where exactly with what error message?

Comment: No crash, just blank page sent to browser by Apache.  I think it is stack overflow because it only happens when I have zend_extensions loaded for debugging, which increases the stack depth.  Just before application under apache gives up, the stack depth is 99, not counting zend.  No error message.

Answer (score 76):

This problem happens more often on Windows platform, because of smaller Apache's default stack size. There is 1 MB default stack size on Windows, unlike 8 MB on Unix/Linux platforms. It could be a reason, why some for example PHP scripts works properly on Linux, but cause crash of Apache on Windows.

Furthermore, the crash is silent (*segmentation fault*), there is no error message, Apache just stops responding and the child process is restarted. Browser gets no data and renders a blank page, so it's a bit difficult to decide what's wrong.

It's a common problem when working with **long regular expressions in PHP**.

There is one notice in Apache's error log only, which tells, that child process crashed:

```
Parent: child process exited with status ... -- Restarting
```

The best way to alter the Apache's stack size is using the **ThreadStackSize** directive in the Apache's configuration file. There is a description of the **ThreadStackSize** directive in Apache's documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#ThreadStackSize

So increase of the Apache's stack size on Windows might looks like this:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

These lines should be put in the Apache's configuration file. For simplicity, you could put it to **httpd.conf**. Or better (but not necessary), put it to **httpd-mpm.conf** file and in *httpd.conf* uncomment this line:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

It sets Apache's stack size to 8 MB, so it's the same as a default value on Linux.

*And don't forget to restart Apache! :)*

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't even have errors in my logs, just that the process exited successfully.

Comment: @Freek, What's your [Apache `LogLevel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel)?

Comment: I have this notice, but increasing `ThreadStackSize` didn't work for me... There is one specific application which breaks my Apache and I can't figure it out :/

Comment: Well, there are multiple reasons for that. You failed to configure it properly (didn't restart Apache, used a wrong configuration file, etc.), the application needs even more than 8 MB stack (or whatever you've configured) or it may even contains an infinite loop, so it will eat the stack, no matter how big it is. Or you may have a completely different root cause of the problem. Try to localize the part of the application which is causing the issue.

Comment: This fixed my issue! I ran into a stack overflow with Symfony on Windows. I had no errors in Symfony logs, or Apache, just info that Apache restarted, but Windows logs were showing that httpd.exe was crashing. After a lot of trial & error I determined I had too many route parameters throughout the application but I set ThreadStackSize and it's all good!

Comment: What is ThreadStackSize for? Why we need to put that? 
Sorry, I can't still understand its technicalities.