# Apache not start on xamp control panel

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When i start Apache on my xamp control panel i get this error in error log:

> Error: [Sat Nov 02 01:47:42.699987 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid
>   5860:tid 228] AH00428: Parent: child process 5848 exited with status
>   1073807364 -- Restarting.

I was google it and search the same problems on stackowerflow, and some solutions are:

- copy mysqllib.dll and some php files to win/system32, but didnt woring for me.

My os is win7 32 bit.

Comment: Thanks Arun, where on this link you see solution? sorry i cant find post where is solution?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058845/how-do-i-increase-the-stack-size-for-apache-running-under-windows-7