# Contact Form 7 Country List in Dropdown

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a problem in Contact Form 7 in WordPress. I use the drop-down menu to create a list of countries and copy the shortcode into the form editor, and then when I save the form, I get a "connection reset" error in my browser and an Apache error. How can I fix this?

I am using localhost, XAMPP 1.8.3, WordPress 3.8.1, and Contact Form 7 version 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, most likely you've got segmentation fault of Apache on Windows.
Please try to increase the Apache stack size as it's written here [How do I increase the stack size for Apache running under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058845/how-do-i-increase-the-stack-size-for-apache-running-under-windows-7)

Comment: This worked for me also on Win10 x64, MySQL 5.6.36, PHP 5.6.31, Apache 2.4.25