# Quoted string with quotes excaped by another quote (two double quotes)

Tags: php, regex, double-quotes

So the regex for a quoted string has been solved over and over. A good answer seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/692331

```
$re_dq = '/"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"/s';
```

Seems to be the standard solution for PHP.

**My Issue** is that my quotes are escaped by another quote. Example:

```
="123 4556 789 ""Product B v.24"""

="00 00 F0 FF ""Licence key for blah blah"" hfd.34"

=""
```

The previous strings should match the following, respectively:

```
string '123 4556 789 ""Product B v.24""' (length=31) 

string '00 00 F0 FF ""Licence key for blah blah"" hfd.34' (length=48) 

string '' (length=0)
```

The examples given are just illustrations of what the string may look like and are not the actual strings I will be matching, which can number in the tens of thousands.

I need a regex pattern that will match a double quoted string which may OR MAY NOT contain sequences of two double quotes.

**UPDATE 5/5/14:**

[See Answer Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494942/692331)

Comment: Do you want `Licence key for blah blah` as a separate matched group?

Comment: No, each line should be a single group

Comment: Can you not replace `'""'` by `''` and then just grab all quoted strings?

Comment: No, I need the quotes to remain so that I can properly escape them later

Comment: you don't need to escape the double quotes if you use them inside  single quotes , ex: `preg_match('/"123 4556 789 ""Product B v\.24"""/', $subject)`

Comment: Why not just call: `str_getcsv($subject)[0];`

Comment: @Tuga, I have no idea what will be in the quoted string. Not to mention there are thousands of them.  I am working with a proprietary database export and processing with with a custom [Lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) in order to convert it to XML.

Comment: @anubhava, I don't think you understand the problem statement..

Comment: Onus is always on OP to explain a problem clearly. After 16 hrs of posting a question and so many comments problem remains unclear with only 1 answer, something is amiss here.

Comment: @anubhava you aren't missing anything the OP is, a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the pattern from [zx81](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23351747/692331)

```
$re_dq_answer = '/="(?:[^"]|"")*"/'
```

results in backtracking after every single matched character.  I found that I could adapt the pattern found at the very top of my question to suit my need.

```
$re_dq_orignal = '/="[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"/s';
```

becomes

```
$re_dq_modified = '/="([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"/';
```

The 's' pattern modifier isn't necessary because the pattern does not using the \s metacharacter.

The longest string I have had to match was 28,000 characters which caused Apache to crash on a stackoverflow.  I had to increase the stack size to 32MB ([linux default is 8mb, windows is 1mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7597506/692331) just to get by! I didn't want every thread to have this large stack size, so I started looking for a better solution.

Example (tested on [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com)): A string (length=3,200) which required 6,637 steps to match using $re_dq_answer now requires 141 steps using $re_dq_modified. Slight improvement I'd say!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Per your request, minor mod to account for empty quotes.

```
(?<!")"(?:[^"]|"")*"
```

Original solution:

```
(?<!")"(?:[^"]|"")+"
```

Demo:

```
<?php
$string = '
"123 4556 789 ""Product B v.24"""
"00 00 F0 FF ""Licence key for blah blah"" hfd.34"';
$regex='~(?<!")"(?:[^"]|"")+"~';
$count = preg_match_all($regex,$string,$m);
echo $count."<br /><pre>";
print_r($m[0]);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
2

Array
(
    [0] => "123 4556 789 ""Product B v.24"""
    [1] => "00 00 F0 FF ""Licence key for blah blah"" hfd.34"
)
```

Comment: @Kenneth FYI Added a demo. Let me know if this is what you are trying to match, and if not what tweaks are needed.

Comment: Appears to work as expected on regex101.com. I will try is in my application in the morning and accept the answer if no issues arise. Thanks!

Comment: Your regex matches everything except an empty string "" (which I did not specify, but have modified the question). One minor mod accounts for that (?<!")"(?:[^"]|"")*" If you will modify the answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Kenneth Per your request, I added your requested mod to the solution. :)